Monotonic Transformations Preserve Relative Probabilities in Continuous Distributions?
I'm struggling to develop a deep intuition for why monotonic transformations preserve relative probabilities in continuous cases. While I understand the idea at a surface level, particularly for discrete cases (where it's easier to think in terms of counts), I lose my intuition when trying to extend this to continuous distributions.
I think I understand the following so far:

A monotonic transformation $f(x)$ (e.g., $f(x) = x^2$ on $x \geq 0$) preserves the order of outcomes. If $x_1 < x_2$, then $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.
In discrete cases, this order preservation combined with the one-to-one nature of the mapping helps me see why relative probabilities don’t change—the counts remain proportional, even though the values are transformed.
In continuous cases, the probability density function (PDF) changes according to the derivative of the transformation:
$$p_Y(y) = p_X(f^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left| \frac{d}{dy} f^{-1}(y) \right|,$$
where $f^{-1}(y)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$. But I’m having trouble connecting this formula to an intuitive/visual understanding of why relative probabilities over intervals remain unchanged.

Where I get stuck:

For transformations like $f(x) = x^2$, which stretches the input space non-uniformly (e.g., $1 \to 1, 2 \to 4, 10 \to 100$), it feels like the larger values might disproportionately dominate the probability. For example, the interval $[10, 11]$ maps to $[100, 121]$, which is much larger than $[1, 2] \to [1, 4]$.
My intuition breaks down because I struggle to reconcile how the adjustment by the derivative $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$ (or $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ for $f(x) = x^2$) "balances" this stretching effect. In a discrete case i can imagine the one to one mapping as simple a relabelling where relative counts stay the same. But for the continuous case i can't find the same satisfaction.

What I’d like to understand:

How does the change-of-variables formula ensure that relative probabilities (e.g., $P(Y \in [a, b]) / P(Y \in [c, d])$) are preserved under monotonic transformations? Is there a way to build intuition for this beyond just trusting the formula?
How should I think about this transformation geometrically? Does it help to think of probabilities as "density mass" that gets redistributed, and if so, why does this redistribution not distort the relative sizes?
Are there specific examples or visualisations that might help bridge my intuition gap, particularly for continuous distributions?

Thank you for any insights!

Essentially for a strictly increasing function $f$, $P(f(Y) \in [f(a), f(b)]) = P(Y \in [a, b])$ since $a \le Y \le b \iff f(a) \le f(Y) \le f(b)$.  Similarly  for a strictly decreasing  function $g$, $P(g(Y) \in [g(b), g(a)]) = P(Y \in [a, b])$ since $a \le Y \le b \iff g(a) \ge g(Y) \ge g(b)$. If you prefer, $\mathbb P({\omega \in \Omega: Y(\omega) \in [a,b]}) =  \mathbb P({\omega \in \Omega: f(Y(\omega)) \in [f(a),f(b)]})$ etc.

I really would prefer to leave a comment, but since I lack the reputation I'm forced to post this as an answer; with that said, I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for.
The preservation of relative probabilities seems pretty intuitive. If $X$ is a continuous random variable with support encompassing $[10,11]$, then the random variable $Y=X^2$ would be in the interval $[100,121]$ with the same probability as $X \in [10,11]$. This seems obvious; it's just the image of the interval under the function defining the transformation.
Thus, in the general case, if $X$ is a continuous r.v., and $Y=f(X)$ for some bijective function $f$, then $P(X\in[a,b]) = P(Y\in[f(a),f(b)])$. It follows immediately that
$$\frac{P(X\in[a,b])}{P(X\in[c,d])} = \frac{P(Y\in [f(a),f(b)])}{P(Y\in[f(c),f(d)])}$$
The change of variables formula is simple to derive from the cdf.
Let $X$ be a cont. r.v. with pdf $f_x(x)$ and cdf $F_x(x)$, and let $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ is a bijection on the support of $X$. Because $g$ is a bijective, continuous function, it is either decreasing or increasing.
Case 1: $g$ is increasing
$$P(Y \leq y) = P(g(X) \leq y) = P(X \leq g^{-1}(y))$$
$$=F_x(g^{-1}(y))$$
Differentiate to get the pdf
$$f_y(y) = f_x(g^{-1}(y)) * \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$$
Case 2: $g$ is decreasing
$$P(Y \leq y) = P(g(X) \leq y) = P(X \geq g^{-1}(y)) = 1 - P(X \leq g^{-1}(y))$$
$$=1 - F_x(g^{-1}(y))$$
Differentiate to get the pdf
$$f_y(y) = -f_x(g^{-1}(y)) * \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$$
But since the derivative here will always be negative, it suffices to write
$$f_y(y) = f_x(g^{-1}(y)) * |\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$$
which holds for both cases.
This shows where the factor of the derivative comes from, and I think it's simpler than a visual explanation. Obviously probabilities are areas under the pdf so if the interval stretches under the transformation then the height must decrease to compensate. How this interaction manifests depends on the transformation and support, so I'd imagine a general geometric explanation to be elusive.
